# send multiple text box names to one jsp page by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two text boxes and i want to send these two text box names to one jsp page. By getting these two names in check.jsp i will do some calculation and will return the result by json to third text box, but i think i am doing wrong somewhere. Can anybody give me an idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#textbox").keyup(function () {// do i need to write another onkey up for another text box?
$.getJSON('check.jsp', {
    textboxname: this.value// here how can i send another text box name to check.jsp?
},function(data){
  // get data
 });
});
});
</script>
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textboxname"/>// name goes to check.jsp
<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="textboxname1"/>// how can i send this text box's
 name to that same check.jsp
<input type="text" id="textbox2" name="textboxname2"/>// here i want to display the 
result received from check.jsp
```

server side(check.jsp)

```
String firsttextboxname=request.getParameter("firsttextboxname");
String firsttextboxname1=request.getParameter("firsttextboxname1");
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject(); 
jsonObj.put("isTrue","true");
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(jsonObj.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" class="submitme" name="textboxname"/>// name goes to check.jsp
<input type="text" id="textbox1" class="submitme" name="textboxname1"/>// how can i send this text box's  

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".submitme").keyup(function () {
         $.getJSON('check.jsp', {
           textboxname: jQuery("#textbox").val(), textboxname2: jQuery("#textbox1").val()
           },function(data){
                if (data.textboxname != "" && data.textboxname2 != "") {
                  jQuery("#textbox2").val(JSON.stringify(data));
                }
                else {
                  jQuery("#textbox2").val("");
                }
             }
         });
       });
     });
</script>
```

------OR AS A POST-----------

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'check.jsp',
  data: { textboxname: jQuery("#textbox").val(), textboxname2: jQuery("#textbox1").val() },
  success: function(data) {
     jQuery("#textbox2").text(JSON.stringify(data));
  },
  dataType: 'JSON'
});
```

I'll comment to say your doing a couple things I wouldn't.

1) Why not send this data via a POST

2) Why send data everytime a key is pressed, why not bind this to a submit button?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer but i need to write two key up events for two textboxes, is n't it?

Comment: i agree with your first one but submit button is not there that's why i want to do it by onkey up events. For Post method i can send data to a servelt?

Comment: Sure, it really depend what your goal is, which isn't clear. Do you really want to submit to the server every time someone presses a key? And you want any key event to submit all the text fields every time regardless of which field fires the event?

Comment: ya i want to submit data to server(one jsp page) by two onkey up events every time for two text boxes, not by submit button manually. Any suggestion please

Comment: so in server will i get these two names by two request.getParameter() methods?

Comment: Yes, one called textboxname and one called textboxname2

Comment: Oops! ok if i want to send to a servlet then i need to give servlet  name? just one doubt you have written second text box name as textboxname1 in html but in jquery you are passing textboxname2

Comment: that data object keys just tell it what parameter key to give it when it sends it to the server. It can be changed to anything with out affecting client side code. Your server code would read it by this key. request.getParameter("textboxname2");

Comment: ya problem fixed! but when i am clearing data from two text boxes then the third text box which is showing result should get auto cleared, but it is not happening, any suggestion? suppose i am adding two text box values and displaying sum in 3rd text box then when i am clearing two textboxes and 3rd text box should get auto cleared, but it is not happening?

Comment: Because you still return a value from your servlet. which is an empty json string {"textbox": "", "textbox2": ""} you could conditionally return "" when both values are "" or handle it on the client side by setting the val("") when both keys' values are blank.

Comment: ya how to do this client side validation, it is not happening

Comment: where i am wrong here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374169/autohide-text-box-when-a-particular-option-is-selected-from-combo/9374193#9374193