# returning sum from server side by json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am adding two text box values by onkey up event. every time data entered, will be submited to the server and then result will be returned by json. I am getting a text box by json(by onchange event of a combo) and another text box is already present in html, when i am changing data in second text box(in html) then total is calculated but when i am changing data in first text box(in javascript) then total is not calculated? Where m i wrong? First and second text boxes have same class **submitme**.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".submitme").keyup(function () {
        $.getJSON('total.jsp', {
        firsttextboxname: jQuery("#firsttextbox").val(), secondtextboxname:
 jQuery("#secondtextbox").val()
        }, function (responseData) {
             var total = responseData.sum;
              $("#thirdtextbox").val(total);// displays total
    });
});


 $("#combo").change(function () {
        $.getJSON('combo.jsp', {
            comboboxname: this.value
        }, function (responseData) {
           // returns a text box (first text box)
     $("#adiv").empty().append("<input type='text' class='submitme' id='firsttextbox' name='firsttextboxname'/>");

    });

 });
});
```

html

```
<div id="adiv">
// getting first text box here
</div>
//second text box whose data is also taken along with first text box each time

 <input type="text" id="secondtextbox" class="submitme" name="secondtextboxname"/>// taking value from this text box to calculate sum

 <input type="text" id="thirdtextbox"/>// auto filling sum here
```

server side(total.jsp)

```
 String a=request.getParameter("firsttextboxname");// getting first text box name
 String b=request.getParameter("secondtextboxname");/ getting second text box name

 int c=Integer.parseInt(a);// converting to integer
 int d=Integer.parseInt(b);//converting to integer

 int e=c+d;// calculating total

 JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject(); 

 jsonObj.put("sum",e);// sending sum to client side

 response.setContentType("application/json");
 response.getWriter().write(jsonObj.toString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you asynchronously add the combo box (or any element) it does not get the keyup event binding.  You have to use .live() like so:

```
$(".submitme").live("keyup", function() {
    // stuff
});
```

See the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for details on how .live() works.

Comment: but when first text box becomes empty then sum is still remaining there without auto cleared why? how can total be cleared when text boxes are cleared?

Comment: use jQuery `.on()` if you are using jQuery1.7.1+

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your adding the keyup events to the ".submitme" classed elements in the domready, but the firsttextbox isnt yet on the document.

its added on your #combo's change event so its not getting a keyup event assigned to it.